# How to use preg_replace_callback?

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-replace-callback

I have the following HTML statement

```
[otsection]Wallpapers[/otsection]
WALLPAPERS GO HERE

[otsection]Videos[/otsection]
VIDEOS GO HERE
```

What I am trying to do is replace the [otsection] tags with an html div.  The catch is I want to increment the id of the div from 1->2->3, etc..

So for example, the above statement should be translated to

```
<div class="otsection" id="1">Wallpapers</div>
WALLPAPERS GO HERE

<div class="otsection" id="2">Videos</div>
VIDEOS GO HERE
```

As far as I can research, the best way to do this is via a preg_replace_callback to increment the id variable between each replacement.  But after 1 hour of working on this, I just cant get it working.

Any assistance with this would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Use the following:

```
$out = preg_replace_callback(
    "(\[otsection\](.*?)\[/otsection\])is",
    function($m) {
        static $id = 0;
        $id++;
        return "<div class=\"otsection\" id=\"ots".$id."\">".$m[1]."</div>";
    },
    $in);
```

In particular, note that I used a `static` variable. This variable persists across calls to the function, meaning that it will be incremented every time the function is called, which happens for each match.

Also, note that I prepended `ots` to the ID. Element IDs should not start with numbers.

---

For PHP before 5.3:

```
$out = preg_replace_callback(
    "(\[otsection\](.*?)\[/otsection\])is",
    create_function('$m','
        static $id = 0;
        $id++;
        return "<div class=\"otsection\" id=\"ots".$id."\">".$m[1]."</div>";
    '),
    $in);
```

Comment: How could you get the `$in` populated with subject ?

Comment: @SheikhHeera That should already be there. I usually use `$in` and `$out` to show where the data goes in and comes out.

Comment: Thanks it looks great and should work, but I keep getting an unexpected T_FUNCTION error, but the quotes and escaped quotes all look good.   http://ideone.com/K71TV

Comment: That's because you're using an old version of PHP. I'll edit with a backward-compatible version.

Comment: @Kolink Amazing! Works perfectly. Thanks so much, will accept once the system timer lets me

Comment: @Kolink : why have you used the word " is " in the 2nd line of your code . I'am a newbie , please help with that .

Comment: `i` is a flag to make it case-insensitive. `s` allows `.` to match newlines.

Comment: Please, not another needless <code>create_function()</code>! Please note: **Caution** 
_This function internally performs an eval() and as such has the same security issues as eval(). Additionally it has bad performance and memory usage characteristics._ [Doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php)

Comment: @MichaelProbst That's why you should upgrade to a version of PHP that has anonymous function support (5.3 or newer). If you're still using 5.2, you have bigger problems than an errant `eval` in disguise ;)

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol : I agree you should be using PHP 5.3+ for security reasons, but even with 5.3+ you still have an `eval()`-Problem if you use `function_create()` instead of an anonymous function. And the example above shows `function_create()`, that's why I warn.

Comment: Thanx for the part "For PHP before 5.3:" ! ... I have v.5.2.6 ... so I have slightly modified the code like this - and it works!

Answer (score 37):

> **Note**: The following is intended to be a general answer and  does not attempt to solve the OP's specific problem as it has already been [addressed before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11174818/1438393).

**What is [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback)**?

This function is used to perform a regular expression search-and-replace. It is similar to [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/str_replace), but instead of plain strings, it searches for a user-defined regex pattern, and then applies the callback function on the matched items. The function returns the modified string if matches are found, unmodified string otherwise.

**When should I use it?**

`preg_replace_callback()` is very similar to [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/preg_replace) - the only difference is that instead of specifying a replacement string for the second parameter, you specify a `callback` function.

Use `preg_replace()` when you want to do a simple regex search and replace. Use `preg_replace_callback()` when you want  to do more than just replace. See the example below for understanding how it works.

**How to use it?**

Here's an example to illustrate the usage of the function. Here, we are trying to convert a date string from `YYYY-MM-DD` format to `DD-MM-YYYY`.

```
// our date string
$string  = '2014-02-22';

// search pattern
$pattern = '~(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})~';

// the function call
$result = preg_replace_callback($pattern, 'callback', $string);

// the callback function
function callback ($matches) {
    print_r($matches);
    return $matches[3].'-'.$matches[2].'-'.$matches[1];
}

echo $result;
```

Here, our regular expression pattern searches for a date string of the format `NNNN-NN-NN` where `N` could be a digit ranging from `0` - `9` (`\d` is a shorthand representation for the character class `[0-9]`). The callback function will be called and passed an array of matched elements in the given string.

The final result will be:

```
22-02-2014
```

**Note:** The above example is for illustration purposes only. You **should not** use to parse dates. Use [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) and [`DateTime::format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) instead. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167916/convert-one-date-format-into-another-in-php) has more details.

Comment: One thing that seems obvious once you know it, but might be worth noting if you're just starting with `preg_` functions, is that in the example `$matches` starts at 1 rather than 0 because 0 contains the entire string that was matched. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/14383726/957246