# Why preg_match() returns first match at index 1 (not 0) of returned array?

Tags: php, preg-match

Im working on small website **scraper** with cURL.

I decided to use preg_match to find header and article content.

This is my code:

```
preg_match('@<h2 class="title">(.*?)</h2>@s', $this->website, $this->title);
            
if(sizeof($this->title) > 1)
    $this->title = trim($this->title[1]); // rewrite first element of array to regular variable
```

I was experimenting with it and I found, that if there is one match - it returns it in array at index 1, not 0.

Edited question: **Why is this 1, not 0? Im doing something wrong?**

My server: Apache/2.4.3 (Win32) PHP/5.4.7

Comment: I know it's not addressing the question, but it's generally considered a bad idea to parse HTML code using regex.

Comment: I cannot reproduce it. Can you post a sample `$this->website` that exhibits the issue? (But please not the complete site, just a short excerpt.)

Comment: @GarethL why you didnt wrote answer? Now i cant accept...

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario sorry for misleading, its indeed not empty element. Anyway, first element of that array is not a matched string, but it doesnt matter, GarethL explained it.

Comment: nitpick: `scrapper` = one that scraps, e.g. destroys, disposes of. you're working on a `scraper` - one that scrapes.

Comment: @MarcB Thank you for highlighting my mistake. My english is not the best.

Comment: Your edit has completely altered the question. What you ask now it just what's explained in the manual page for the function.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario there are many PHP manuals for many languages. In my language many functions are documented very bad. I probably should read english docs...

Comment: And one more thing @ÁlvaroG.Vicario - his answer showed me, that I asked wrong question.

Comment: Yeah, I stopped using the Spanish manual when I learn that `mail()` had 5 arguments :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default behaviour of preg_match is to return the entire string which was matched in the result array at index 0, then each matched sub-pattern in subsequent result array indexes. If nothing was matched, the result array is empty. If something is matched, you get the full string that was matched and then any sub-patterns.

Comment: You are awesome. You've answered the edited question 3 minutes before it was edited :)

Comment: He just answered correctly to wrong question :) Sorry, my fault.