# PHP - Using back references with file_exists in preg_replace

Tags: php, preg-replace, file-exists, backreference

I am trying to replace content of some tags in included files with content from other files:

```
$view = preg_replace('/{include ([[:alnum:]\.-]+)}/', ((file_exists('template/$1.html')) ? 'OK $1' : 'KO $1'), file_get_contents('myTemplateFile.tpl'));
```

All the `{include file.ext}` references I got in `myTemplateFile.tpl` are replaced with `KO file.ext` instead of `OK file.ext`.

However, if I hardcode `file_exists('template/file.ext')`, then the right string is displayed.

It appears to me the back-reference is not correctly resolved inside the `file_exists` call.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
preg_replace('/{include ([[:alnum:]\.-]+)}/', ((file_exists('template/$1.html')) ? 'OK $1' : 'KO $1'), file_get_contents('myTemplateFile.tpl'))
```

This first executes `file_exists('template/$1.html')`, then passes `OK $1` or `KO $1` (likely the latter) to `preg_replace`, which then replaces all occurrences.

You'll have to use a callback to make this work, not call `file_exists` as argument:

```
preg_replace_callback(
    '/{include ([[:alnum:]\.-]+)}/',
    function (array $m) {
        return file_exists("template/$m[1].html") ? "OK $m[1]" : "KO $m[1]";
    },
    file_get_contents('myTemplateFile.tpl')
)
```

Comment: Thanks! I did not pay attention to the way recursive calls were resolved... Of course file_exists is called first before preg_replace is even being evaluated!

Answer (score 1):

```
$view = preg_replace(
    '/{include ([[:alnum:]\.-]+)}/', 
    ((file_exists('template/$1.html')) ? 'OK $1' : 'KO $1'), 
    file_get_contents('myTemplateFile.tpl')
);
```

The above code is executed as follows:

```
$contents = file_get_contents('myTemplateFile.tpl');

if ((file_exists('template/$1.html')) {
    $result = preg_replace('/{include ([[:alnum:]\.-]+)}/', 'OK $1', $contents);
} else {
    $result = preg_replace('/{include ([[:alnum:]\.-]+)}/', 'KO $1', $contents);
}
```

As you can see, the `file_exists()` call is performed **before** the `preg_replace()` statement. It is checking for the existence of the file `"template/$1.html"`, where **`$1` is a literal string which has no special meaning**. That file doesn't exist, and the `else` block (originally `'KO $1'`) will always get executed.

In short, you can't use the backreferences from `preg_replace()` function *outside* the `preg_replace()` function. The solution is [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback):

```
preg_replace_callback(
    '/{include ([[:alnum:]\.-]+)}/',
    function ($m) {
        return file_exists('template/'.$m[1].'html') ? 'OK '.$m[1]: 'KO '.$m[1];
    },
    file_get_contents('myTemplateFile.tpl')
);
```

See also:

- [How to use preg_replace_callback()?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21631013/)

Comment: Thanks for your help, although you are second... Gave a +1 anyway as a reward ;o)

Comment: Well my bad. However, the other answer explains step-by-step where the problem comes from, having helped me to remember how recursive stuff are being processed. :oP I hope you won't have hard feelings towards me about still being second... ;o)